# Почему содержимое массива не меняется внутри метода onCreate

Tags: java, android-studio, switch

Программированием занимаюсь недавно.
Пишу простенькое приложение для андроид для умного дома.
Есть массив из 6 элементов. Каждый элемент может быть либо 0 либо 1.
Есть 6 свитчей которые в зависимости от положения должны записывать 0 или 1 этот в массив. Но не могу понять почему они этого не делают.... При выводе массива на экран выдает все "0".

```
 int direct[] = new int[5];
 public String d()
 {
    return Arrays.toString(direct);
 }

 public void directional(int d, int z)
 {
    direct[d] = z;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one__floor__menu);

    light_fasad = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.light_fasad_id);
    light_fasad_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.light_fasad_text);
    light_fasad.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
  b)
        {
            if(light_fasad.isChecked())
            {
                light_fasad_text.setText("Освещение ФАСАД: включено");
                //nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                directional(0, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                light_fasad_text.setText("Освещение ФАСАД: выключено");
                //  nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                directional(0, 0);
            }
        }
    });

    light_til = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.light_til_id);
    light_til_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.light_til_text);
    light_til.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
  b)
        {
            if(light_til.isChecked())
            {
                light_til_text.setText("Освещение ТЫЛ: включено");
                //nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                directional(1, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                light_til_text.setText("Освещение ТЫЛ: выключено");
                //  nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                directional(1, 0);
            }
        }
    });

    light_terassa = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.light_terassa_id);
    light_terassa_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.light_terassa_text);
    light_terassa.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
  b)
        {
            if(light_terassa.isChecked())
            {
                light_terassa_text.setText("Терасса освещение: включено");
                //nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                directional(2, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                light_terassa_text.setText("Терасса освещение: выключено");
                //  nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                directional(2, 0);
            }
        }
    });

    power_terassa = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.power_terassa_id);
    power_terassa_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.power_terassa_text);
    power_terassa.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
  b)
        {
            if(power_terassa.isChecked())
            {
                power_terassa_text.setText("Терасса розетки: включено");
                //nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                directional(3, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                power_terassa_text.setText("Терасса розетки: выключено");
                //  nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                directional(3, 0);
            }
        }
    });

    light_koridor = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.light_koridor_id);
    light_koridor_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.light_koridor_text);
    light_koridor.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
  b)
        {
            if(light_koridor.isChecked())
            {
                light_koridor_text.setText("Коридор освещение: включено");
                //nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                directional(4, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                light_koridor_text.setText("Коридор освещение: выключено");
                //  nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                directional(4, 0);
            }
        }
    });

    dush_pol = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.dush_pol_id);
    dush_pol_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dush_pol_text);
    dush_pol.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
  b)
        {
            if(dush_pol.isChecked())
            {
                dush_pol_text.setText("Душевая ИК-пол: включено");
                //nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                directional(5, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                dush_pol_text.setText("Душевая ИК-пол: выключено");
                //  nasos_xvs_text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                directional(5, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Кусок кода в другом активити

```
  One_Floor_Menu one_floor = new One_Floor_Menu();
   String message_one_floor()
   {
      String mof = one_floor.d();
      return mof;
   }
```

Comment: Для чего в вопросе *"кусок кода в другом активити"*? что за класс `One_Floor_Menu` и как связан с проблемой? Сам код будет менять значения в массиве `direct[]` при изменении соответствующих чекбоксов, здесь все правильно. Если вы рассчитываете, что при старте в массив будут получены текущие значения чекбоксов, то этого не произойдет - слушатель реагирует только на изменения (код в слушаетеле будет выполнен, только когда пользователь изменит состояние чекбокса). Опишите подробнее, в чем именно вы видите проблему в вашем коде. Что и когда должно происходить и что  происходит вместо этого.

Comment: Если `One_Floor_Menu` это активити, то вы не можете создавать собственные экземпляры через оператор `new` и ожидать, что это будет работать (абсолютно точно это не будет работать). Активити -  системный компонент с жизненным циклом, ее экземпляры может создавать только система и выполнятся в текущий момент времени будет только та активити, которая находится на переднем плане (видима в данный момент на экране). Ваш объект `one_floor` - мертвый код, который не исполняется таким образом, когда речь идет о системном контроллере виджетов (активити)

Comment: Зачем вам вообще этот массив `direct`? Если речь о умном доме, то текущее состояние переключателей вы должны получать от контроллеров этого умного дома и с ними взаимодействовать для изменения этого состояния, а не записывать их в какой то массив, который к тому же будет уничтожен при выходе из приложения (а есть определенная вероятность, что и при переходе в другую активность) и все записанные значения будут утрачены. Перед тем, как писать приложение вам нужно разработать четкое ТЗ, как именно все будет работать.

Comment: Для чего в вопросе "кусок кода в другом активити"? что за класс One_Floor_Menu и как связан с проблемой?
У меня есть 5 активити (Menu, Under_Floor_Menu, One_Floor_Menu, Two_Floor_Menu, Information_Menu). Главное меню, 3 этажа дома и информационное меню.

Comment: Физически у меня есть дополнительные контакты, которые сигнализируют положение автоматов и контакторы - то, чем я могу управлять. Также есть программируемое реле ПР200. Ко входам которого это все подключено. В активити каждого этажа есть два лайоута. На одном свитчи которыми я управляю, а второй просто показывает мне положение всех автоматов

Comment: Для активити каждого этажа есть массивы info и direct. В зависимости от положения ключей массивы direct заполняются нулями и единицами. Затем они соединяются и передаются на пк. Контроллер подключен к пк. Программа на пк будет привязываться к тегам выходов контроллера и за счет полученного массива раскидывать какие теги включить, а какие выключить. Массив инфо наоборот. Прога на пк определяет по тегам состояние входов контроллера вормирует массив из 0 и 1 и отправляет на телефон

Comment: One_Floor_Menu это активити 1ого этажа

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя создавать активити оператором `new` и рассчитывать, что они будут работать, система не исполняет жизненный цикл запущенной таким образом активити и колбэк `onCreate()`, соответственно тоже исполняться не будет, как и изменятся значения массива.

Могу предложить писать состояния свитчей в хранилище, не зависящее от жизненного цикла активити (а не в массив). Так как значений у вас всего 6, можно использовать `SharedPreferences`, такой механизм реализовать проще, но решение костыльное. Правильно в таких случаях использовать БД, продвигаемая сейчас Google концепция *Architecture Components* отлично подойдет для реализации и позволит манипулируя данными из любого места, получать их визуализацию (положение свитчей на экране) автоматически (состояние виджетов привязывается к данным в БД). Таким образом вы сможете получить доступ к актуальному состоянию своих свитчей из любого запущенного правильным образом активити, прочитать их и изменить значение.

Еще, как вариант, можно переопределить класс `Application` и хранить свой массив `direct` в нем, создав там методы доступа и модификации этого массива. Так как `Application` стоит на вершине иерархии классов и существует, пока существует приложение, вы можете обращаться к своему массиву из любого места программы, читать и изменять его содержимое. Возможно для вас это будет более удобный вариант. Простой [пример использования](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945297/7566397).
Необходимо учесть, что с закрытием приложения текущее состояние массива будет потеряно и при следующем старте в него необходимо считать актуальное состояние свитчей.